# PHP error mysql_num_rows returns expects boolean error. is my query wrong?

Tags: php

mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in line 33

```
if($password!=$password_again){
            echo'password did not match';
        }else{
            $query="SELECT username FROM users WHERE 'username'='$username'";
            $query_run=mysql_query($query);


            if(mysql_num_rows($query_run)==1){
                echo'the username'.$username.'already exists';  
            }else{
                echo'ok';
            }
        }
```

Comment: `echo mysql_error(); var_dump($query);` + read about `mysql_real_escape_string()`

Comment: Add `echo mysql_error();` just after `mysql_query()` call and see what it says.

Comment: @zerkms up-voted because you're the only one who mentioned `mysql_real_escape_string()`

Comment: One side note to OP: look at your keyboard and find that wide key below character keys. Yes, it's space. Yes, it's used in code to separate tokens. And to make the code readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`'username'='$username'` Change this to `username='$username'`

Comment: Ah yes, here it is. However, why not teach OP how to debug his code? ;P

Answer (score 4):

Getting a boolean back from mysql_query means there was an error - either there's a syntax error in the query (which yours has), or something else blew up (e.g. failed to connect first).

Change the query call to

```
        $query_run=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

The syntax error I can see is due to bad quotes

```
        $query="SELECT username FROM users WHERE 'username'='$username'";
                                                 ^--------^----
```

when you quote a field name like that, it's no longer a field name - it's just a string. However, this isn't an SQL syntax error, it's a logic error as you're doing an invalid comparison, and not comparing the real username against the username field in the database.

Comment: The quotes OP wanted were `, actually (worth noting).

Comment: Maybe, but `username` isn't a mysql reserved word, so backticking it is totally useless.

Answer (score 0):

Your SELECT query looks incorrect:

```
$query="SELECT username FROM users WHERE 'username'='$username'";
```

Should probably be something like

```
$query="SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
```

i.e. do not put the column name in single quotes. But even that is dangerous - it opens your code to SQL injection attack.

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing a check to see if mysql_query is returning a resource or FALSE prior to sending it to the mysql_num_rows. Please take a look at the documentation here for proper usage:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

In your case you're passing a FALSE to the mysql_num_rows function and that is why you're getting that error.

Answer (score 0):

mysql_num_rows expects a MySQL resource.  $query_run is being set to false because your query is erroring, due to the single quotes around 'username' in your WHERE clause.

Comment: No, it's a logic error, but not a syntax error. `where 'a'='b'` is a perfectly valid SQL construct - it'll just evaluate to false and return no rows, while `where 'a'='a'` will be true and return ALL rows.

Comment: I didn't write that it was a syntax error. Although, I could have clarified that a resource would be returned in the event that he attempted to run the query with $username set explicitly to 'username' resulting in a true boolean assertion.

Comment: Yes, you did, the query won't return false because it IS a syntactically valid query. It'll just return unexpected results because the query's logic is flawed. A query which returns no rows is not an error, it's just a query with no results - a statement handle with a row count of zero. NOT false.

Comment: Marc, I clearly understand his query's syntax is perfectly valid.  The OP asked if his query was "wrong," not "syntactically accurate," and my answer reflected that the query was "erroring," which encompasses a logical error.  By all means, feel free to down vote if you disagree with the answer.  There's no need to leave argumentative comments over minor semantics of my answer.